# Application.COMAddIns Subscript out of range

Tags: c#, excel, com, vsto, add-in

Following the sample case below

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608614.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Run into a 'Subscript out of range' in

`Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("ExcelImportData")`

New to VSTO and C#. How do I debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the add-in subscript is out of Range, it suggests that you've either made a typo in the name of the add-in while creating the VSTO project, or you've failed to open Excel using the debugger (which automatically loads the add-in).

You can ensure that Excel is loading properly by adjusting the Project Properties in Visual studio:

[image]

Above, my full path to Excel is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe

Then, once you've pressed F5 to start Excel, you can check the loaded COM add-ins by clicking on the COM add-ins button on the Developer tab.

[image]