# Subscript out of range error at Word Load - VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, 32bit-64bit

I have worked on a project whose final outcome is a word add-in and it is a collaboration of a VSTO addin (Word ribbon) + C# dll set + Macro Enabled template (MyProject.dotm).

The project development has been finished and now working on the advanced installer part (doing by other person). 
We have call code in VSTO addin from VBA (MyProject.dotm) as per this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-in-a-vsto-add-in-from-vba?view=vs-2019).
There will be two separate installers will get created for 32bit and 64bit.

Now my issue is, we are getting the Visual basic run time error, `Runtime error '9' : Subscript out of range` when load word after the product installation (64bit machine with Word 64 bit).

I have searched on the error and found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431469/application-comaddins-subscript-out-of-range), and was able to fix the error by

Setting the **Start Action** (under debug - project properties) for the VSTO project as **Start external program** and its value as **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.exe** and build the project, replace the dll set of the installer (C:\Program Files\MyProject) with the new dlls of the project and load word.

Now my question is,

I want to find a global fix that will work with both 32bit and 64bit machines and both 32bit and 64bit office. Is there any fix that I can apply to the project to fix this error? or should this need to be fixed in the installer?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019) by Microsoft.

> You must create a specific set of registry entries when you deploy
>   VSTO Add-ins that are created by using Visual Studio. These registry
>   entries provide information that enables the Microsoft Office
>   application to discover and load the VSTO Add-in.
>
> When you build your project, Visual Studio creates these registry
>   entries on the development computer so that you can easily run and
>   debug the VSTO Add-in. If you use ClickOnce to deploy your VSTO
>   Add-in, the registry entries are automatically created on the end-user
>   computer. If you use Windows Installer to deploy your VSTO Add-in, you
>   must configure the InstallShield Limited Edition project to create the
>   registry entries on the end-user computer.

and I have add the required registry value as per the article and it solves the **Runtime error '9' : Subscript out of range** error.